# System Administrator can not see custom field even when FLS is configured correctly

Tags: custom-field, standard-objects, ant, field-level-security, system-admin

My user has the System Administrator profile. When I go to Object Manager > Task > Fields and Relationships I can only see standard fields, but not any of the custom fields that this object has, and when I perform a retrieve of the object's metadata using ANT, I can't retrieve any of its custom fields either.

This is the FLS of the Task object for the System Admin profile. All the fields are visible and editable:

[image: Field level security of Task object]

And the profile also has granted the "View All" and "Modify All" permissions, which according to documentation should give me full access to all the standard objects like this one.

I can also see the custom fields from the developer console when I open Task.obj, but I cannot access these fields from ANT or from Fields and Relationships.

Any idea why is this happening? Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 4):

Custom fields for the Task object are managed in the Activity object in Setup > Object Manager.  Note that custom fields for Event are also managed in the Activity object.